# Heteroskedasticity and Type I, Type II Error

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, type-i-and-ii-errors

If one is conducting a hypothesis test for heteroskedasticity, would one generally consider a Type I or a Type II error more serious? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: If you don't mention the actions that would result from rejection or non-rejection, how could we even guess at their relative consequences? Please describe the situation and why you are testing this. What difference does it make to what you're doing if you reject or not?

Comment: Andrew Gelman has been quoted as saying, "We are rarely concerned with Type I error because we rarely believe it is possible for the Type I hypothesis to be strictly true/"

Comment: @DJohnson It's true enough for point nulls, but composite nulls can easily be true

Comment: @Glen_b  Interesting! Would you clarify the distinction?

Comment: @DJohnson You mean the [distinction between a point (/simple) null and a composite null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis#Terminology)? The simplest case would be a one-tailed test ... *point*: $H_0: \mu=\mu_0$ vs *composite* $H_0: \mu\leq\mu_0$. While there's little chance in general that $\mu$ exactly equals $\mu_0$ it's not hard to think of cases where the composite null above might actually occur.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the explanation. Is it relevant or would it change your answer that AG is a Bayesian? In other words, since Bayesians don't subscribe to the N-P hypothesis framework, would they also reject the N-P distinction that you've proposed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Andrew Gelman is certainly capable of answering questions about hypothesis testing within the framework of hypothesis testing. He does so regularly. So I'm not sure what you're asking in relation to a question framed as a question about how hypothesis tests work. The quote you offer appears to be within that framework

Comment: @Glen_b Is your assumption that there is a single framework for hypothesis testing? My understanding is that Bayesians don't subscribe to the N-P framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you reject homoscedasticity and opt for using robust standard errors instead when homoscedasticity is actually present, you lose efficiency and finite sample properties. Asymptotically however your model inference will be still be valid.

However, if you opt for non robust standard error, and heteroscedasticity is present, your inference is always plain wrong.

If you do applied research (or industry work) you should clearly always use robust errors, you lose nothing if your wrong - provided your sample is large - whereas the other way around you loose the ability to do valid inference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is contained in @Glen_b 's initial comment:  To know if a type I or type II error is more serious, you have to know the consequences of each.

Is it better to be late to a party or early to a party?  Well, the Red Queen imprisons all those who show up late for her parties, and the White Queen imprisons all those who show up early for her parties.  So, it depends on whose party you are going to.

The OP doesn't give any context to why this hypothesis test is being conducted.

But imagine you are conducting an initial screening trial of several treatments, with only a few observations for each treatment.  Here, our hypothesis tests are likely to have low power, and we want to be sure to retain several treatments for future testing. In this case, we are likely to be more tolerant of type I errors, and want to avoid type II errors.  False positives can be weeded out later.  But we don't want to miss a potentially-useful treatment by making a false-negative error.

For an opposing case, if we are comparing a new medical treatment to an established one, we will likely want to accept a type-II error over a type-I error.  A false positive will cost lives and money.  A false negative may mean we miss out on a new potentially-important treatment.  But what's lost with the false negative is only the marginal improvement of the new treatment relative to the established one.

Obviously, there are other considerations that come in to play in these kinds of decisions.

As a side note, the answer by @Repmat suggests that the question is posed relative to testing for homogeneity of variance as a precedent to conducting another analysis, say, a *t*-test or anova.  The OP doesn't indicate that this is in the context of the question.  But if it is, it's worth pointing out that it is generally not recommended to determine the type of test conducted (e.g. Student's *t*-test vs. Welch's *t*-test) contingent on the results of another hypothesis test (e.g. a test for homogeneity).

---

Source:  I've used similar examples [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/D_01.html).